# drop NaN in pandas python

Tags: python, pandas, nan

Cant figure out why `.dropnan()` is not dropping cells with NaN values?

help please, I've gone through the pandas documentation, dont know what Im doing wrong????

```
import pandas as pd
import quandl

import pandas as pd

df = quandl.get("GOOG/NYSE_SPY")
df2 = quandl.get("YAHOO/AAPL")

date = pd.date_range('2010-01-01', periods = 365)

df3 = pd.DataFrame(index = date)

df3 = df3.join(df['Open'], how = 'inner')

df3.rename(columns = {'Open': 'SPY'}, inplace = True)

df3 = df3.join(df2['Open'], how = 'inner')

df3.rename(columns = {'Open': 'AAPL'}, inplace = True)

df3['Spread'] = df3['SPY'] / df3['AAPL']

df3 = df3 / df3.ix[0]

df3.dropna(how = 'any')

df3.plot()

print(df3)
```

Comment: It is not an inplace operation. Either `df3.dropna(how='any', inplace=True)`  or `df3 = df3.dropna(how='any')` would work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

change `df3.dropna(how = 'any')` to `df3 = df3.dropna(how = 'any')`

Comment: Most of pandas `DataFrame` methods have an `inplace` argument (by default `False`) that controls if the result should be a copy (how it's use in this answer) or if the method should modify the caller (how it was used in the OP question).

Answer (score 1):

I tried to replicate your problem with a simple csv file:

```
In [6]: df
Out[6]:
     a    b
0  1.0  3.0
1  2.0  NaN
2  NaN  6.0
3  5.0  3.0
```

Both df.dropna(how='any') as well as df1 = df.dropna(how='any') work. Even just df.dropna() works. I am wondering whether your issue is because you are performing a division in the previous line:

```
df3 = df3 / df3.ix[0]
df3.dropna(how = 'any')
```

For instance, if I divide by df.ix[1], since one of the elements is a NaN, it converts all elements of a column in the result to NaN, and then if I remove NaNs using dropna, it will remove all rows:

```
    In [17]: df.ix[1]
    Out[17]:
    a    2.0
    b    NaN
    Name: 1, dtype: float64

    In [18]: df2 = df / df.ix[1]
    In [19]: df2
    Out[19]:
         a   b
    0  0.5 NaN
    1  1.0 NaN
    2  NaN NaN
    3  2.5 NaN

    In [20]: df2.dropna()
    Out[20]:
    Empty DataFrame
    Columns: [a, b]
    Index: []
```